# Form keydown in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I use these codes to inform users when they press a button and show them in a message box that you have pressed a button. In the winform I have a button, so these codes won't working until I change button1 tabstop to false. and when I click on the button after that it won't tell users that they're pressing a button.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("You have pressed A");
   }
}
```

These codes won't working until I change tabstop of the button to false. Help to how can I do that and let the users know when they pressed a button in any time.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the KeyPreview property of form to true from designer. It will work

Comment: btw does user control have this ability,too? because i have a usercontrol but I should change its button tab stop to false. user control has KeyPreview property or something?

Comment: no there is no KeyPreview like property for user control. But even if user control is added on form setting then KeyPreview on form to true will work even if focus is on user control.